# dotnet core3.1 how to remove Dependencies, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Analyzers

Tags: .net, .net-core, duplicates, dependencies

**How to remove the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Analyzers? My project got two analyzers in Dependencies, how to remove?**

[image: How to remove the MVC.Analyzers?]

[image: I got errors. But i dont know how to fix.]

Comment: open csproj and delete the 2.2 analyzer entry